# Feeding DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute error messages with resource stored string value pairs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, data-annotations, resx, validationattribute

My `ValidationAttributes` don't access my `ErrorMessages` value-pairs stored in a `.resx` Resource File generated with `VS2010` built in resource generator. (Add New Item - Resources File)

I simply added a folder named `Resources`, then added a new `Resources File` and called it `ErrorResources`, in the resources editor I added a value pair `StringLengthError` - Too Long**.

Then in my DataAnnotation.ValidationAttribute I wrote:

```
  [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 3, 
                    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorResources),
                    ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthError")]
  public string Details { get; set; }
```

I added a `using` statement to include the `ErrorResources`.

But when I run it, the ValidationAttribute StringLength is totally void.

If I use it without the ErrorResources, as in :

```
  [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 3)]
  public string Details { get; set; }
```

The validation attribute comes back to life.

I tried accessing the `ErrorResources` value pairs in other part of the code, and it works. I just can't get my ValidationAttributes to use the ErrorResources resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access modifier should be `Public` but that's not enough.
You will have to change properties of your resx file to look like this:

[image: Properties]

Pay attention to `Build Action` and `Custom Tool`

In addition `Resx` used by data annotations should sit in `App_GlobalResources` rather than in `Resources` you've mentioned. Try these, see if that works alright.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes that's the answer, Custom Tool is also important.

Comment: @user1353914 If that's the answer that was most useful and helpful, please mark it as accepted one. Thanks to you too .

Comment: You seem to be very new to stackoverflow.com. Welcome & Enjoy & Good luck. You *click on V mark* (it says "click to set this answer as your accepted answer").

Answer (score 0):

Try change `Access Modifier` setting of Resources File to `public` !

[image]

Comment: Hi:

I forgot to say that I already did that, and nothing happened!
Furthermore, there's a project that I downloaded (some article that explains ValidationAttributes) that uses this kind of error messages in resources, it happened that the resources defined by this guy work, but I created a resource file in this project, and my resources didn't work in that project.
I don't know why, could it be something related to the culture, but if so, why didn't it work in that project?, I don't kno what to think.
This is the project:
https://github.com/jeffhandley/RIAServicesValidation

Comment: If I use the resouce files that are already present in that project, then it works, but defining new resource files, even in the same directoy, don't work